# The method free() is undefined for the type GLFWKeyCallback

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, free, glfw

I have installed the stable LWJGL 3.0.0b version and I am trying to follow the window creation example found at https://www.lwjgl.org/guide. However, I am getting the "The method free() is undefined for the type GLFWKeyCallback" and "The method free() is undefined for the type GLFWErrorCallback" errors. The free() method was supposed to be in the GLFWKeyCallback and GLFWErrorCallback classes but, apparently, it is not there. How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Here is the code from https://www.lwjgl.org/guide:

```
import org.lwjgl.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    // We need to strongly reference callback instances.
    private GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback;
    private GLFWKeyCallback   keyCallback;

    // The window handle
    private long window;

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello LWJGL " + Version.getVersion() + "!");

        try {
            init();
            loop();

            // Destroy window and window callbacks
            glfwDestroyWindow(window);
            keyCallback.free();
        } finally {
            // Terminate GLFW and free the GLFWErrorCallback
            glfwTerminate();
            errorCallback.free();
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        // Setup an error callback. The default implementation
        // will print the error message in System.err.
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback = GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err));

        // Initialize GLFW. Most GLFW functions will not work before doing this.
        if ( glfwInit() != GLFW_TRUE )
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");

        // Configure our window
        glfwDefaultWindowHints(); // optional, the current window hints are already the default
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE); // the window will stay hidden after creation
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE); // the window will be resizable

        int WIDTH = 300;
        int HEIGHT = 300;

        // Create the window
        window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Hello World!", NULL, NULL);
        if ( window == NULL )
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");

        // Setup a key callback. It will be called every time a key is pressed, repeated or released.
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
                if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_RELEASE )
                    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE); // We will detect this in our rendering loop
            }
        });

        // Get the resolution of the primary monitor
        GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        // Center our window
        glfwSetWindowPos(
            window,
            (vidmode.width() - WIDTH) / 2,
            (vidmode.height() - HEIGHT) / 2
        );

        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        // Enable v-sync
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        // Make the window visible
        glfwShowWindow(window);
    }

    private void loop() {
        // This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
        // OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
        // LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
        // creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
        // bindings available for use.
        GL.createCapabilities();

        // Set the clear color
        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        // Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
        // the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
        while ( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GLFW_FALSE ) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

            glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers

            // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
            // invoked during this call.
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloWorld().run();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code in the Getting Started section only works with the latest nightly build. There have been some API changes since 3.0.0b - in this case, just use `release()` instead of the newer `free()` (but remember to change it back when 3.0.0 is released).